# How to lock "full screen mode" a program on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, kiosk

When I say "Full screen mode" I mean without any borders and with no option to maximize/minimize with the mouse or keyboard shortcuts.

I want to make a "kiosk windows 7" with a program that is preinstalled, so if I do it wrong, I can't format. My problem is to set an application (a kid's game program) running in full screen and block users (kids) to doing anything else.

EDIT:
My goal is to make Windows 7 Professional running an application without any users touching the system, only the application. For that I need to have a scheduled task to open the program, block keyboard shortcuts to exit, and delete permissions to users to access the control panel or registry editor.
I know that I can do most of this with gpedit.msc, but I don't know how to prevent users to close the application via mouse. This PC is for kids, so you should understand what I'm asking for, a "bulletproff kids PC" from zero.

Comment: It may be beneficial for you to read ***[ask]***, then edit your post with more details of what you are trying to accomplish, what research you've done, and what you have attempted so far. Also include information about the software and any errors you have received.

Comment: I added more details, I think now it's clear

Comment: why don't get some OSes designed specifically for kids like edubuntu?

Comment: Now you have clarified what you want, but you still have not told us what you have researched or attempted. At this point, it sounds like you want us to do the research for you. If that is the case, it isn't how this site works.

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc - I can't do that. I wish I could or at least I have the right OS Disk.
CharlieRB - I don't know what kind of research do you think I can do for a simple task (I thought it must be easy). I mean, I said that I've been working with gpedit, but the problem that I want to resolve is about some shortcut or option that allows me to do only that. I couldn't find an easy answer to that, so I supposed that it must be a bit more complicated. Sorry if my post sounds like a "do my homework", but I think that writing here "I searched a lot on Google, help me!" doesn't really care.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with any program. You must use a special tool for this purpose, a program that acts as 'guardian' for the PC.
Such programs are used in internet cafes but are not too cheap to get.